# actionscript tdd frameworks

Tags: actionscript, tdd

Any list of Testing frameworks for ActionScript 2.0/3.0 around there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlexUnit is the "official" unit testing framework. It's owned by Adobe's Research guys I believe.

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/ActionScript_3:resources:apis:libraries

Here's a tutorial on how to use it:

http://langexplr.blogspot.com/2008/10/creating-flex-unit-tests-with-flexunit.html

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2010-05-18**

Since this post is a little old and I just received an upvote, it's probably worth providing some updated information so people don't chase down old frameworks.

The original fluint team now produce the official (and open source) **unit testing** framework, [FlexUnit](http://www.flexunit.org). You also might want to check out [asunit](http://asunit.org/), particularly if you need AS2 support.

[flexcover](http://code.google.com/p/flexcover/) is the go-to **code coverage** framework, and requires you use an alternate compiler.

You have a bit more choice for **mocking/isolation frameworks**, since most use dynamic proxy generation now:

- [asmock](http://asmock.sourceforge.net) supports a strongly typed record-replay-verify mocking model and (I hope) a pretty comprehensive wiki to get started. (Though I'm a tad biased here :)
- [mockito](http://bitbucket.org/loomis/mockito-flex/wiki/Home) supports supports a strongly typed arrange-act-assert syntax
- [mockolate](http://github.com/drewbourne/mockolate) is from the same author as [mock-as3](http://code.google.com/p/mock-as3/) (now discontinued) and provides an alternate model for mocking (though requires you specify method names as a string)
- [mock4as](http://code.google.com/p/mock4as/) is a static mocking framework

Answer (score 2):

Try [AsUnit](http://www.asunit.org/). It currently supports ActionScript 2.0 and 3.0 development. And, it's open source.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [fluint](http://code.google.com/p/fluint/)

> Based loosely on the concepts of FlexUnit and its ancestor JUnit, fluint provides enhanced asynchronous support, a graphical test runner, integration with continuous build systems and an optional Adobe AIR client for directory watching.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AS3Unit](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/yossy/AS3Unit/en/index) from libspark. They also have an async beta test kit.